# Rock-Paper-Scissor-Lizard-Spock grame

Tags: android

I am new to android as well as java. Currently I am prgramming an android app "Rock-Paper-Scissor-Lizard-Spock game". I have a program with code below

```
String s = computer.getText().toString(); // s is random string uploaded on screen by computer

    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
        scissor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //if user presses scissor button

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scissorCutsPaper();
                }
        });
        lizard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //if user presses lizard button

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lizardEatsPaper();
            }
        });
        paperWrong(); // if user presses other buttons (other than scissor and lizard)
    }
```

- The `scissorCutsPaper()` displays the users is correct.
- The `lizardEatsPaper()` displays the users is correct.

The `paperWrong()` is supposed to be called when other buttons(other than scissor and lizard) is called!!! BUt it seems not works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add individual listeners to the other buttons too and call `paperWrong()` from there.

Example:

```
 rock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //if user presses scissor button

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            paperWrong();
            }
    });
```

**Edit**

You could implement the `onClickListnener`.

```
OnClickListener wrong=new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    paperWrong();
} 
};
rock.setOnClickListener(wrong);
spock.setOnClickListener(wrong);
```

Adding this to your code will make sure that when either buttons `rock` or `spock` are clicked `paperWrong()` is called.

Comment: @ManojKumar Sure, you could create parameterized listeners etc. But if you don't have a listener on each button how will they listen?!

Comment: @ManojKumar You can, just create a function that implements onClickListener and set that as the listener for the other buttons.

Comment: Okay man. Thanks :)
gonna do that.. Once it work.. I will get back to u guys..  :)

Comment: @ManojKumar - Please check the updated answer, it's lesser code.

Comment: @ManojKumar Please accept the answer then by clicking the tick mark to the top-left corner of my answer.